# Iconographic attributes of Devi Durga?

Tags: identification-request, devi, goddess, durga

I use a translator, I speak Spanish.
Could someone please describe the attributes of the image you sent? Arms, Head, lion horse, the headdress on his head? Who are the ones that show up there? And if there is a specific name for this representation of Mother Durga? And a text that describes it, with the attributes that are in the image?
Thank you so much.
Vanessa

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely not any specific Devi murti.I think the Above is just an artist's Attempt at a Portraying the Vishvarupa (Cosmic Form) of the Mother Goddess. They probably just took some artistic liberty to draw the extra details such as  head on the top of her head.

We find similar descriptions of Devi's Cosmic form in multiple scriptures  bearing innumerable heads and arms.

> **Kurma Purana I.12.51-59**

[image]
[image]

[**Skanda PurAna, Prabhāsa Khaṇḍa, Vastrāpatha-kṣetra-māhātmya, Chater 9,
Verse 49-62**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc627164.html)

> Himavān said:
>
> O you goddess of broad eyes, who are you? Tell me. I have a strong doubt. The goddess said:
>
> Know me to be the greatest power resorting to Maheśvara, whom those desirous of liberation look upon as unique, immutable and one
> (only).
>
> **I shall give you divine sight. See my divine form.** Speaking this much the Goddess herself gave special power to Himavat.
>
> **(Himavat) saw the Highest Lord, resembling crores of suns, an
> orb of light, clear, encompassed with the row of thousand flames,
> resembling hundreds of destructive fires at the end of the world,
> fearful due to the fangs, exciting, adorned with a mass of matted
> hair, very calm, of a mild face, full of endless wonders, having signs
> like the lunar digits, having lustre like that of crores of moons,
> having a crown, with a mace in his hand, adorned with anklets, having
> put on a divine chaplet and garments, having smeared the body with
> divine fragrant substances, holding a conch and a disc, desirable,
> having three eyes, clad in hide, residing in the Egg (of the universe)
> and out of it, being external, internal and the highest, full of all
> power, bright, (and adorned) with all ornaments, whose lotus-like feet
> were saluted by Brahmā, Indra, Upendra and best yogins, who reached
> everything with His hands and feet, and eyes, head and face, and who
> remained after having occupied everything.**
>
> Seeing the Lord of Nandī, the highest one, i.e. Maheśvara,
> along with the Goddess, the king, Himālaya Mountain, full of fear and
> (at the same time) delighted in mind, concentrating himself,
> remembering Oṃkāra, praising Him with eight thousand epithets, again
> saluted him, and spoke with folded hands: **“O highest goddess, I am now
> afraid of your divine form that has come up. So (please) show another
> (form).”**

*It's Notable that although the form described above seems that of Shiva, Devi refers to it as her form only(owing to non-duality b/w both).*

**[Devi Bhagavata, Book 7, Chapter 33](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57424.html)**

> 21-41. Vyāsa said :-- "O King! Hearing the words of Girirāja, Viṣṇu
> and all the other Devas gladly seconded him. **Then the Devī, the
> Goddess of the Universe, knowing the desires of the Devas, showed Her
> Own Form that fulfils the desires of the Bhaktas, that is auspicious
> and that is like the Kalpa Vrikṣa towards the Bhaktas. They saw Her
> Highest Virāṭ Form. The Satyaloka is situated on the topmost part and
> is Her head; the Sun and Moon are Her eyes; the quarters, Her ears;
> the Vedas are Her words; the Universe is Her heart; the earth is Her
> loins; the Bhuvarloka is Her navel; the asterisms are Her Thighs; the
> Maharloka is Her neck; the Janarloka is Her Face; the Taparloka is Her
> head, situated below the Śatyaloka;** **Indra and the Devas and the
> Svarloka is Her arms; the sound is the organ of Her ears; the Aśvin
> twins, Her nose; the smell is the organ of smell; the fire is within
> Her face; day and night are like Her two wings. The four-faced Brahmā
> is Her eyebrows; water is Her palate; the juice thereof is Her organ
> of taste; Yama, the God of Death, is Her large teeth; the affection is
> Her small teeth; Māyā is Her smile; the creation of Universe is Her
> sidelooks; modesty is Her upper lip; covetousness is Her lower lip;
> unrighteousness is Her back. The Prajāpati is Her organ of generation;
> the oceans are Her bowels; the mountains are Her bones; the rivers are
> Her veins; and the trees are the hairs of Her body. O King! Youth,
> virginity, and old age are Her best gaits, positions or ways (courses)
> paths, the clouds are Her handsome hairs; the two twilights are Her
> clothings; the Moon is the mind of the Mother of the Universe; Hari is
> Her Vijñāna Śākti (the knowledge power); and Rudra is Her
> all-destroying power.** The horses and other animals are Her loins; the
> lower regions Atala, etc., are Her lower regions from Her hip to Her
> feet. The Devas began to behold Her this Cosmic (Virāṭa) appearance
> with eyes, wide awake, with wonder. Thousands of fiery rays emitted
> from Her form; She began to lick the whole universe with Her lips; the
> two rows of teeth began to make horrible sounds; fires came out from
> Her eyes; various weapons were seen in Her hands; and the Brāhmaṇas
> and Kṣattriyas are become the food of that Awful Deity. Thousands of
> heads, eyes and feet were seen in that form. Crores of Suns, crores of
> lightnings flashes, mingled there. Horrible, Awful, That appearance
> looked terrific to the eyes, heart and mind. The Devas thus beheld and
> began to utter cries of horror and consternation; their hearts
> trembled and they were caught with immoveable senselessness. "Here is
> the Devī, our Mother and Preserver." This idea vanished away at once
> from their minds.

Comment: @user30068     Thank you very much for the answer and the references to the texts but I need the name of the attributes in Sanskrit or Hindi that are in your hands, the weapons and things, for example, conch, lasso, sword, mace and others, as well as the name of the nine beings on the side right and left that come out of his head example, ganesaha, vishnu shiva and others the details of his headdress above the head the snakes their names and those of those goddesses that are there. Thank you for your understanding, I hope you help me.